# Why does CakePHP formhelper not translate months?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, formhelper

I would like to see a Dutch translation of the CakePHP 2.3.7 formhelper months. See this link: http://dev4.west-dyke.com/verhuur/reserveren.

However I can't seem to get it working. I also saw another post about this problem, but it still didn't solve the problem.

I created a folder named app/Locale/nl_NL/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po. The PO file was generated with poedit from cake.pot in the app/Locale directory.

I added these lines to cake.po:

```
msgid "January"
msgstr "Januari"

msgid "February"
msgstr "Februari"

msgid "March"
msgstr "Maart"

msgid "April"
msgstr "April"

msgid "May"
msgstr "Mei"

msgid "June"
msgstr "Juni"

msgid "July"
msgstr "Juli"

msgid "August"
msgstr "Augustus"

msgid "September"
msgstr "September"

msgid "October"
msgstr "Oktober"

msgid "November"
msgstr "November"

msgid "December"
msgstr "December"
```

I added the following line to the bottom of my bootstrap.php file:

```
Configure::write('Config.language','nl_NL');
```

Does anybody have an idea of what's going wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's caused by caching? You can test that by changing the values in the default config file and see whether they show up in your select.

Comment: @Pieter I am working in development mode, so caching is disabled.

Comment: OK, if you change the `default.po`-file, are the changes showing up (in English)?

Comment: Yes, when I call echo __('August'); it echoes my Dutch translation from default.po. However the months in the form haven't changed.

Comment: Mind your casing: "app/locale/" should be "app/Locale/". Even though on windows both will work you should always respect the casing to avoid issues in the future or other OS.

Comment: @mark This was a typo in the message, not in my test case. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you try `Configure::write('Config.language','nl-nl');`? If I remember correctly, locale config languages are set via dash, not underscore.

Comment: No, the `Config.language` should be same as the directory name.

Comment: I was taking a look at the core - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L188 - with locale and language being to different things. But if you are certain this is the case..

Comment: Looking at the test cases you seem to be write. It should be `nl_nl`.

Comment: Well my regular dutch translation shows correctly, it's only the months generated by the formhelper that don't.

Comment: How you got multiple nl versions? Or why are you not just using the simple `APP\Locale\nld\LC_MESSAGES\cake.po` path and locale? This definitely works for me with deu/nld.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple nl versions? Do you mean the locale notation nl_NL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright I fixed it, I did the following to get multi language and a Dutch translation of the CakePHP formhelper months working:

1 - I created a folder named app/Locale/nl_NL/LC_MESSAGES

2 - I ran ./Console/cake i18n extract through the console

3 - I added the following lines to cake.pot:

```
msgid "January"
msgstr "Januari"

msgid "February"
msgstr "Februari"

msgid "March"
msgstr "Maart"

msgid "April"
msgstr "April"

msgid "May"
msgstr "Mei"

msgid "June"
msgstr "Juni"

msgid "July"
msgstr "Juli"

msgid "August"
msgstr "Augustus"

msgid "September"
msgstr "September"

msgid "October"
msgstr "Oktober"

msgid "November"
msgstr "November"

msgid "December"
msgstr "December"
```

4 - I used poEdit to create .po (and .mo) files from default.pot and cake.pot. I placed the .po (and .mo) files inside the earlier created folder.

5 - I placed the following line inside bootstrap.php:

```
Configure::write('Config.language','nl_NL');
```

Comment: Note that [the localized plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/localized/blob/master/Locale/nld/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po) contains translations for Dutch already for you.

Comment: @AD7six Thanks, copying that cake.po file should save me from creating it.

Answer (score 1):

They use a different translation domain (e.g. cake, cake_dev). You'll have to translate these files. See __d function.

Comment: I have already translated default.po, cake.po and cake_dev.po. This didn't help.